# How to remove video effect in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my API class today we learned how to show the camera with the  tag. We also learned how to add effects with JavaScript. But, I'm stuck on how to reverse these effects. How would I make the clear button clear the current effect?

````js
<body>
  <h1>Magic Camera</h1>
  
  <div class="tools">
    <button id="sepia">Sepia</button>
    <button id="">Clear</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="scene">
    <img src="billboard.jpg">
    <div class="video-container">
      <video id="myCamera" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    </div>

  <script>
    var myDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
    var permissions = {
      audio: false,
      video: true
    };
    myDevices.getUserMedia(permissions).then(showCam);
    function showCam(stream){
      $("#myCamera")[0].srcObject = stream;
    }
    function addEffect(event){
      var effect = event.currentTarget;
      var filter = `${effect.id}(1)`;
      $("#myCamera").css("filter", filter);
    }
    $("button").click(addEffect);
  </script>
</body>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myCamera').css('filter', '');
```